# Trouble setting password via googleapiclient

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I'm having trouble setting passwords via the Python Google API.  Here's a summary of what I'm doing:

```
from googleapiclient import build
import hashlib

password = 'secret'
hashed_password = hashlib.sha1(password).hexdigest()
params = {'password': hashed_password}

# 'http' is a httplib2.Http() object with the appropriate credentials to
# access the Google API
directory = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)

username = 'batman@batcave.org'
directory.users().update(userKey=username, body=params).execute()
```

The code executes without any errors, but the password is not being set to the expected value.

Do I need to tell the API that the password was hashed with SHA-1?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
params = {'password': hashed_password, 'hashFunction': 'SHA-1'}
```